# Disable "Could not switch the monitor configuration"

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors, laptop

Is there a way to *disable* the popup that says "Could not switch the monitor configuration"?

[image: Could not switch the monitor configuration \n could not set the configuration for CRTC 634]

I am only interested in *disabling* the popup, not fixing the underlying problem.

I am constantly switching monitor setups with my laptop, and don't expect it to work all the time. The problem is the popup prevents the system from fixing itself. I have to click 'close' on one or two of these popups before my monitor will come on by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fix this problem, use: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227071&p=7704699#post7704699

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on an Ubuntu 16.04 guest in VirtualBox 6. My screen is a QHD+ and by giving the virtual machine more video memory (128MB), the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I run 14.04 and I could not add new resolution mode for external monitor since intel graphics drivers could not be updated. 
Combining replies from different pages the solution is the following

Run cvt command for desired resolution. Since default refresh rate did not work here I added a third parameter with lower refresh rate that default one (60 Herz)

cvt 2560 1440 40

This returned
/#2560x1440 39.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 58.98 kHz; pclk: 201.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync

Based on reply these commands should be run 
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_40.00"   201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440_40.00"

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "2560x1440_40.00"

The last one selects the new resolution. In order to save the option (avoid running on startup) you can create .xprofile file, paste above lines into file and give it right permissions.

touch $HOME/.xprofile

chmod +x $HOME/.xprofile

I have created two resolution values for Dell-P2416D

xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_40.00"   201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440_40.00"

xrandr --newmode "2304x1296_50.00"   206.00  2304 2456 2696 3088  1296 1299 1304 1336 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2304x1296_50.00"

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "2304x1296_50.00"

Hope it helps.